# Are the Clean Shaven Officer and the Old Man supposed to be the same person?

Tags: character, the-x-files

In the first episode of the new season of The X-Files we see flashbacks to the UFO crash at Roswell and there is a character who is listed officially as Clean Shaven Officer. He is reported to be a doctor or a man of science and seems to be the only one on the site not there to simply cover up truth. He protests the murder of the alien crawling from the crash and carries it from the scene wrapped in a blanket.

Later, in present day, Mulder meets with an Old Man, who we've not met in the original series. He appears to be a new counterpart to Deep Throat or Mr X, providing Mulder with vague clues to find the truth. This man has a beard and glasses and appears to be old enough to have been at Roswell and he tells Mulder that Roswell was a smoke screen.

**Are the Old Man and the Clean Shaven Officer the same person?**

Comment: I guess you'll have to wait for the next episodes for a definitive answer, but I don't think the episode left much room for doubt. The old man says he's a man of medicine, and we instantly flash back to his younger self, who has the same glasses and the same mole.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [The X-Files Review: "My Struggle"](http://www.pastemagazine.com/articles/2016/01/the-x-files-review-my-struggle.html), they are the same character played by two actors, [Giacomo Baessato](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0046420/) in the flashback scenes and [Rance Howard](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0397555/) in the present day.

For proof, note that the actor Rance Howard has a mole on his left cheek, which was added using make-up to Baessato for the flashback scenes.